# SELECT Failed. 3504: selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group

Tags: teradata

I'm trying to run following query:

```
SELECT  vtiger_products.productcategory AS "Product Category",
        SUM(vtiger_inventoryproductrel.quantity) AS "Line Item Qt"
  FROM bi_batch.vtiger_inventoryproductrel
       INNER JOIN bi_batch.vtiger_products
       ON vtiger_inventoryproductrel.productid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need a group by clause, you don't have one for your non-aggregated column. try adding "group by vtiger_products.productcategory"

Comment: Got it, I have to add GROUP BY 1 or GROUP BY vtiger_products.productcategory or GROUP BY "Product Category". Thanks!

Comment: but does that means I have to put all the select columns in Group By?
I'm converting a mysql to teradata sql, in that query Select is calling 20 columns but Group by just have 2 columns (1 of which is not called in select). I though SQL basics are same in both.

Comment: Teradata, being a "real" database, has much more formal requirements.  MySQL has a **lot** of non-standard extensions and this is one of them.  In "pure" SQL, you must "group" by all non-aggregate columns.  I suggest going to the Teradata web site; download and read the SQL manuals for your version.